# What component of an OS implement device files?

Tags: linux, file, operating-system, device, device-driver

Are device files of devices (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) implemented by some component inside an OS (more specifically, Linux or Unix-like OS)?

Are device files of devices implemented by any of the following components of the IO system of an OS:

- "device-independent OS software",
- "device drivers", or
- something else in an OS?

See Tanenbaum's Modern OS's sketch of layers of the I/O software system, where the OS consists of the middle three layers:

[image]

I learned that devices files belong to the interface provided by device drivers, so I think device files are implemented by device files.

But device files are intended to allow users treat different devices   in an uniform way as files in file systems. That makes me think that device files belong to the interface provided by the outmost component of an OS, which according to the sketch is "device-independent OS software".

So I am not sure.

Comment: Implemented by file systems & device drivers. The [linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) wikipage has more relevant explanations & figures

Comment: Thanks. (1) in the implementation of device files, are file systems in a layer on top of the layer for device drivers? (2) Is it correct that  "device-independent OS software" doesn't implement device files?

Comment: I'm not sure that *all* the details of Tanenbaum's book apply *exactly* to every OS (in particular to Linux). If you want to understand Linux kernel, read material dedicated specifically to it (there are many good books and web sites on Linux kernel). So your questions might not have any sense (for Linux)

Comment: how about my question in (1)? Do you know a sketch of IO software system of Linux which explicitly shows where device files are implemented?

Comment: All operations go through the Virtual File System. Part of its implementation can be found located at `/fs/read_write.c`. Reading the code, you can find out that every file has operations associated with it, which were initialized by a device driver or a file system. These operations are called by generic functions in the VFS.

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge A FILE is defined in the C library and never appears in kernel code.  On the other hand, A struct file, is a kernel structure that never appears in user programs. 
The file structure represents an open file. (It is not specific to device drivers; every open file in the system has an associated struct file in kernel space.) It is created by the kernel on "open" and is passed to any function that operates on the file, until the last "Close". After all instances of the file are closed, the kernel releases the datastructure.
So it is like you want to perform certain operations on the device, it is provided by the operating System through file structures, it is not like any implementation inside os.
First you got to have an clear idea of device Drivers and kernel and if possible know about file descriptors also :) You can find plenty of open source literature on Linux kernel and Device Drivers, surf through them and have fun.
Good luck